# How to use enum with description in xamarin form picker

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have some enums with Description annotation and I want to show description text instead of the enumValue in the picker in xamarin form
I know how to use enum values in the picker but I can't convert and convertback enum decription in the picker
would you help me with this ?

Comment: [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Use an IValueConverter